# Sterling Map Editor : Conditional Null Value

Tags: ibm-sterling

I have a XML to XML map on IBM Sterling B2B Integrator map.

I am trying to set an empty tag on a conditional variable as follows:

```
empty($my_var[counter][1].#my_var);
```

The result is that on output the empty tag does not show up.

Expected result:

```
<my_var/>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The XML element should be declared as mandatory in the map.
The PCDATA property should not have Mandatory checked if it is not required, but the element level should be mandatory.

Note also this known problem:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21701246